# Java Process did not quit after Future task completion

Tags: java, executorservice, concurrent.futures

This is my code snippet using Future.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FutureDemo{

    public FutureDemo(){

            /* Future */
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
                    MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable((long)i);
                    Future<Long> futureResult = service.submit(myCallable);
                    Long result = null;
                    try{
                            result = futureResult.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    }catch(TimeoutException e){
                            System.out.println("Time out after 5 seconds");
                            futureResult.cancel(true);
                    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                            System.out.println("Error: Interrupted");
                    }catch(ExecutionException ee){
                            System.out.println("Error: Execution interrupted");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Result:"+result);
            }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
            FutureDemo fc = new FutureDemo();
    }

    class MyCallable implements Callable{
            Long id = 0L;

            public MyCallable(Long val){
                    this.id = val;
            }

            public Long call(){
                    return id;
            }
    }
}
```

output:

```
D:\Study\Java>java FutureDemo
Result:0
Result:1
Result:2
Result:3
Result:4
Result:5
Result:6
Result:7
Result:8
Result:9
-
```

After submitting all Future tasks, I got the result but still the program did not quit. My cursor is blinking and java process did not quit till I click **CTRL+C**. What is the issue?

**EDIT**: I can't shut down the executor service unless shut down hook is triggered with server shut down.

Comment: This will execute the callables serially: because you're calling `get` in the loop, it will wait until the result is ready (or timeout or exception) before submitting the next callable.

Comment: But I got all the results as edited in the question.

Comment: Sure, but they are scheduled and executed in sequence. Try putting a sleep in the callable, so that 0 would be slower than 1 (say, sleep for 4 seconds if val == 0). You'll see that 0 will still complete before 1.

Comment: On a different note, which is better for setting time out? Future Or CountDownLatch with thread size 1 and time out after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `service.shutdown()` to tell the `ExecutorService` not to wait for any more tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. In my use case, I can't shutdown the service till shut down hook is triggered in server.